# Quick go to folder option in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3

I use *Go to Anything* (cmd + p) frequently in Sublime when I want to quickly jump to a **file** in a project.

I'd like similar functionality to quickly jump to a **folder** in a project in the sidebar.

For example, say I have a project that has a `views` folder nested a few layers deep, ex `/app/resources/views/`.

If I want to see the contents of that folder in the sidebar, I have to goto `app`, then `resources`, then `views`.

Instead, I'd like to be able to quickly type in `views` and have it navigate me there.

Have shopped around various packages but can't quite find one that does this.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for https://github.com/freewizard/SublimeGotoFolder

Comment: Close, but a couple major drawbacks. 1) Doesn't recursively search through folders, just shows first level folders. 2) When you choose a folder, it opens it in a new window, rather than focussing you there in the current window/sidebar. I'd like to frequently jump amongst different folders, and this would end up creatings *lots* of new windows.